# CompletableFuture with Kafka's callback methods?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, completable-future

We're building a small wrapper library around Kafka. We're using older version where there is no `.whenComplete((response, throwable) -> {...});` when calling `kafkaTemplate.send(...);`.

Instead our library is doing following:

1 Defining a `RetryTemplate` bean:

```
@Bean
public RetryTemplate prodRetryTemplate() {    
   final RetryTemplate template = RetryTemplate.builder().maxAttempts(3)
         .retryOn(TopicAuthorizationException.class).exponentialBackoff(1000, 2, 2000).build();
   return template;
}
```

2 Defining a asynchronous CompletableFuture method:

```
@Override
@Async(EXECUTOR_SERVICE) //we had defined Executor bean, it is ommited here
public CompletableFuture<DtoResponse> asyncSend(final Integer key, final String topic, final String message)
      throws Exception {

   final ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord = buildRecord(key, topic, message);

   DtoRespons[] responseHolder = new DtoRespons[1];
   template.execute(ctx ->{

            final ListenableFuture<SendResult<Integer, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);
            future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<Integer, String>>() {

               @Override
               public void onSuccess(final SendResult<Integer, String> result) {
                  log.info("success...");
                  responseHolder[0] = DtoResponse.builder()
                        .error(null)
                        .success(true)
                        .msg("PUBLISHED")
                        .build();
               }

               @SneakyThrows
               @Override
               public void onFailure(final Throwable ex) {
                  log.error("error...)
                  throwError(producerRecord, eventName, ex); //do additional logging
               }
            });

      return null; //to satisfy execute method from RetryTemplate
   });

   return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(responseHolder[0]);
}
```

My question is straightforward, is it possible that once `asyncSend` is called that it returns `null` i.e. will line `return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);` be executed before `onSuccess` or `onFailure` are invoked?

That is, from client side:

```
public void myService(){  
  MyLib lib = new MyLib();
  CompletableFuture<DtoResponse> future = lib.sendAsync(key, topic, message);
  future.whenComplete((result, throwable) -> { 
     //is it possible that result and throwable both be null ??

    });
}
```

Update 1:

Based on professor's Gary comment. I am not sure if this is what you meant:

```
@Override
@Async(EXECUTOR_SERVICE)
public CompletableFuture<SendResult<Integer, String>> asyncSend(final Integer key, final String topic, final String message)
      throws Exception {
   final ProducerRecord<Integer, String> producerRecord = buildRecord(key, topic, message); //this can throw ex

   ListenableFuture<SendResult<Integer, String>> x = template.execute(ctx -> {
      final ListenableFuture<SendResult<Integer, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord);

      return future;
   });
   CompletableFuture<SendResult<Integer, String>> completable = x.completable();

   return completable;
}
```

Then the client code would have to check for `throwable` and for `SendResult<Integer, String>` within `.whenComplete()`. But this is not what I need. With  `SendResult<Integer, String>` client code still cannot tell whether messages is sent or not. How to circumvent this? Please let me know if I've explained this in understandable way. Also, our library needs to do important logging in `onFailure` and `onSuccess`

Update 2:

After Gary's EDIT.

Thanks Gary for helping. However, at first this works, but problem occurs when exception as thrown. In that case `whenComplete` is not invoked, neither is `exceptionally` channel invoked. Let me explain.

So since we use secure Kafka in our `.yaml` file there are these properties:

```
 properties:
  security.protocol: "SASL_SSL"
  sasl.mechanism: "OAUTHBEARER"
  sasl.login.callback.handler.class: "path.to.LoginCallBack"
  sasl.jaas.config: >-
    org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule
      required
      oauth.token.endpoint.uri="sso-uri"
      oauth.ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=""
      oauth.ssl.truststore.type="JKS"
      oauth.client.id="kafka-client-id"
      oauth.client.secret="someSecret"
      oauth.username="username"
      oauth.password="password";
```

I had changed value `oauth.client.id` to `dummy` in order to provoke `org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to construct kafka producer` and to see where the flow will end up.

When line `kafkaTemplate.send("so75823718", "foo");` is reached, it throws exception and that exception is not `ex` in `whenComplete`

```
    @Bean
ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
  return args -> {
        try {
            CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future 
             = foo.asyncSend("foo");
            future.whenComplete((sr, ex) -> {
                if (sr != null){
                    System.out.println("success");
                } else if (ex != null){
                    System.out.println("fail");
                }
            });
        } catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("not expected nor desired behavior 
            to have exception here");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried couple of things, but not worth of showing since they don't even compile. So my question is now, is it somehow possible to not force users of `asyncSend` to use try/catch instead just to use `whenComplete()` or `acceptThen/exceptionally` and that all error handling is done in `asyncSend`?

UPDATE 3:

Really hopping that is a final edit.

So I think I managed it like so:

First, template

```
@Value("${kafkaExceptions:}")
private List<String> exceptions = new ArrayList<>();

    @Bean
    public RetryTemplate template() throws ClassNotFoundException {
       exceptions.add(TopicAuthorizationException.class.getName());
       RetryTemplateBuilder retryTemplateBuilder = RetryTemplate.builder().maxAttempts(retries).retryOn(TopicAuthorizationException.class);
       for (String exceptionClassName : exceptions){
          retryTemplateBuilder.retryOn((Class<? extends Throwable>) Class.forName(exceptionClassName));
       }
       return retryTemplateBuilder.exponentialBackoff(1000, 2, 2000).build();
    }
```

Then,

```
@Async("exec")
public CompletableFuture<SendResult<K, V>> asyncSend(K key, String topic, V message, S) throws Exception {

   return template.execute(ctx -> {

      try {
         ProducerRecord<K, V> producerRecord = buildHeader(key, topic, msg); //can throw custom exception

         return kafkaTemplate.send(producerRecord).completable();
      } catch (Exception e){
         
         if (reThrow(e)) throw e;

         return CompletableFuture.failedFuture(new CustomException(Enum.KAFKA_EX_PROD_PUBLISH_ERROR.findErrorMessage(),e));

      }
   });

}


private boolean reThrow(Exception e){
   String retriableException = e.getClass().getName();
   return retriableExceptions.contains(retriableException);
}
```

In this way I control `execute` invocations. I just need two confirmations.

1. Can I be sure that if in `.whenComplete`, `sr` is non-null, that means that is equivalent of `onSuccess` (from ListenableFutureCallback) callback was called? There will be some business logic if `sr` is non-null.
2. I can be sure that if in `.whenComplete`, `th` is non-null, that happened either because `onFailure` (from ListenableFutureCallback) happened or I completed future with failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`completedFuture`

You are returning an already completed future, regardless of whether the callback has run yet; so the caller will always see a completed future.

You should return `future` from the execute method, then return `future.completable()` from the `asyncSend`.

Note that, starting with version 3.0, the template returns a `CompletableFuture` instead of a `ListenableFuture`.

**EDIT**

I just tested it and it works as expected...

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class So75823718Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So75823718Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    NewTopic topic() {
        return TopicBuilder.name("so75823718").partitions(1).replicas(1).build();
    }

    @Bean
    ApplicationRunner runner(Foo foo) {
        return args -> {
            CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = foo.asyncSend("foo");
            future.whenComplete((sr, ex) -> System.out.println(future + ": " + sr.getRecordMetadata()));
        };
    }

    @Bean
    TaskExecutor exec() {
        return new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor();
    }

}

@Component
class Foo {

    RetryTemplate template = new RetryTemplate();

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Async("exec")
    public CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> asyncSend(final String message) throws Exception {

        return this.template.execute(ctx -> {
            final ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = kafkaTemplate.send("so75823718", "foo");

            return future;
        }).completable();
    }

}
```

```
java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture@7ebce1f7[Completed normally]: so75823718-0@12
```

**EDIT2**

...and to catch direct exceptions on the `send()`...

```java
public CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> asyncSend(final String message) throws Exception {

    CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
    try {
        CompletableFuture<SendResult<String, String>> fut = this.template.execute(ctx -> {
            return kafkaTemplate.send("so75823718", "foo");
        }).completable();
        fut.whenComplete((sr, ex) -> {
            if (ex != null) {
                future.completeExceptionally(ex);
            }
            else {
                future.complete(sr);
            }
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        future.completeExceptionally(ex);
    }
    return future;
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is to provide to client code (i.e. library clients), what Kafka library from 3.0.0 is already providing, the possibility to use .whenComplete instead of ListenableFutureCallbacks. Yeah, we use 2.8.5 I think. Let me try to update based on your suggestion

Comment: Yes; it's what I meant; I just tested it and it works fine; I added my test to my answer.

Comment: Some exceptions (e.g. `SerializationException`) are thrown by the send; there is no future in those cases. If you want to hide that from the caller, you will need to return your own future and complete it (normally or exceptionally when the template's future completes, or exceptionally if the `execute` throws an exception.

Comment: Hopefully, last edit this time.

Comment: I think you are over complicating it (having to check for retryable exception). See my second edit.

Comment: Tnx Gary for your time really. However with EDIT 2, if send() throws Exception (SerializationException, TopicAuthorizationExc) it goes to catch clause and I lose the purpose of RetryTemplate. Possible solution to place in catch blockK `int currentCount = ctx.getRetryCount();

if (isRetriableException(e)) {
   //decreasing 'retries' by 1, since 'ctx.getRetryCount();' starts from zero
   //max attempts reached, wrap KafkaException
   if (currentCount == (retries-1)) throw new MyExc(KAFKA_EX_PROD_PUBLISH_ERROR.findErrorMessage(), e);
   throw e;
}`

Comment: 'private boolean isRetriableException(Throwable t){

   //base case 1
   if (t == null){
      return false;
   }

   //base case 2
   String exceptionName = t.getClass().getName();
   if (retriableExceptions.contains(exceptionName)){
      return true;
   }
   return isRetriableException(t.getCause());
}'

Comment: Don’t put code in comments. It doesn’t make sense to retry a serialization exception, but you have a point about auth exceptions.